# using factory in the controller return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I am trying to send value from my view to the controller using function inside `ng-click` , then use that value to pass it to my factory which goint to pull data from rest api link , but the value im sending return nothing without errors, here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, idService) {
    $scope.getSo = function (id){
        $scope.myIDs = idService.getID(id); 
    };
});
app.factory('idService', function($http,$q) {
    var oGetID = {};
    oGetID.getID = function(id) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://citysdk.dmci.hva.nl/CitySDK/pois/'+id).then(function(response){

             deferred.resolve(response.data);
     });
    return deferred.promise;
    };
    return oGetID;
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <a href="#" ng-click ="getSo('52527290c5cddb0a7cb654ca');">send variable</a>
        {{myIDs.location.address.value}}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the console result of the response[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous call doesn't work the way you are expecting here. Then happens asynchronously and they return return the data based on API server call. You should expect value after a ajax succeed, by putting `.then` over it. As internally `$http` method's return `promise`.

```
idService.getID(id).then(function(response){
   alert(response);
   $scope.myIDs = response;
})
```

Comment: i already try it but it did not work, if you try to alert $scope.myIDs it returns undefind

Comment: @ahmdabos put alert inside `.then` function, it will get called when ajax succeeded

Comment: its return undefind also

Comment: @ahmdabos do `console.log(response)` check what it print

Comment: it return the result currectly , but why its now showing it in the view

Comment: @ahmdabos could you please update `response` content inside your question please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126966/discussion-between-ahmdabos-and-pankaj-parkar).